# Having same filename appdelegate.h for 2 targets in 1 project

Tags: ios, xcode

Is it possible to have separate out AppDelegate.h for different targets: iPhone/iPad?

I have a default common main.m:

```
#import <UIKit/UIKit.h>

#import "AppDelegate.h"

int main(int argc, char *argv[])
{
    @autoreleasepool {
        return UIApplicationMain(argc, argv, nil, NSStringFromClass([AppDelegate class]));
    }
}
```

I have 2 targets setup correctly with an appdelegate.h/.m for each target in each iPhone/ iPad folder.

They header files are similar and it is complaining about `Duplicate interface definition` from the iPad appdelegate.h when I build the iPhone target. However, the reverse just builds ok.

How can I fix this?

Answer (score 3):

You should go to the "Build Phases" for each of your targets and make sure each of your targets includes the appropriate app delegate under "Compile Sources". If you give these two app delegates different classes, you might also want to change `main.m` to use the appropriate one:

```
#import <UIKit/UIKit.h>

#import "IphoneAppDelegate.h"
#import "IpadAppDelegate.h"

int main(int argc, char * argv[])
{
    @autoreleasepool {
        if (NSClassFromString(@"IphoneAppDelegate"))
            return UIApplicationMain(argc, argv, nil, @"IphoneAppDelegate");
        else
            return UIApplicationMain(argc, argv, nil, @"IpadAppDelegate");
    }
}
```

---

Personally, I prefer to have a single app delegate, and put conditional checks for iPhone/iPad, e.g.,

```
if (UI_USER_INTERFACE_IDIOM() == UIUserInterfaceIdiomPad) {
     // do iPad specific stuff
}
```

versus

```
if (UI_USER_INTERFACE_IDIOM() == UIUserInterfaceIdiomPhone) {
     // do iPhone specific stuff
}
```

While it looks unwieldy, much of the app delegates will be the same on the two platforms and it introduces a code maintenance issues to have two app delegates.

Comment: Too many if else statements in a single app delegate, hence not using a single file.

Comment: @NoraOlsen If you want two different app delegate classes, you could (a) include the appropriate one for each of your target's respective "Compile Sources"; and (b) have `main.m` grab the right one. You could theoretically give them the same name, but some of Xcode's UI can get confused in that scenario, so unique names may be better.

Comment: Wouldn't I end up with the `redefinition` problem because I'm including both header files in `main.m`? It seems that I need to do a #if/#else to avoid that in main.m together with a preprocessor macro? Even without explicitly stating the 2 different header file names, Xcode will include all header files thus I was having the original problem of the iPad appdelegate.h being included in my iPhone target. I have also tried user search path ordering.

Comment: @NoraOlsen No redefinition problem because I've given them unique class names. It's just like when you import the header for a weakly linked class, where importing the header doesn't require the presence of the class. I tested the above and it works fine. But if you give these two classes the same name, then you'd have to do that preprocessor check logic. By the way, if you use my approach and if your other classes need to interact with the app delegate's custom objects/methods, then you might want to define a protocol that specifies the common interface.

Answer (score 0):

One way would be to add a "Preprocessor Macro" in the build settings of your target so, for example in your iPhone target you put "BUILD_FOR_IPHONE=1" and in your iPad "BUILD_FOR_IPHONE=0". Then you can add in your iPhone's AppDelegate.h the following

```
#if BUILD_FOR_IPHONE
<your normal .h contents>
#endif
```

and in your iPad's

```
#if !BUILD_FOR_IPHONE
....
#endif
```

Answer (score 0):

I don't know exactly for iPhone and iPad targets, but

If you have two different build Targets in project, you can specify different files to be included in the build by simply selecting appropriate Target Membership for different AppDelegate files.

To have two AppDelegate.m for different build targets:
- First, make your AppDelegate.m only checked for one build target.
- Second, in order to create a copy, go to finder and look for your original AppDelegate.m; create subfolder and copy the file there.
- Now, create the reference in Xcode: drag the file to Xcode window next to original AppDelegate.m, check "create reference" and only select second build target.

At this point you should have two AppDelegate.m in your project next to each other.